# ForEach does not work with @State property in preview

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a list in my view

`@State var capturedColors: [CGColor] = []`

I use ForEach to create a subview based on the list

```swift
ForEach(0..<(capturedColors.count), id: \.self) { index in
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).fill(Color(capturedColors[index])) // ...
}
```

A new item will be appended into the list when a button is tapped.

The view gets updated correctly when the app runs on a physical device, but it does not show anything in the preview.

I did something like this in the preview:

```swift
struct CaptureView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previewColors = [
        CGColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    ]
    static var previews: some View {
        CaptureView(previewColors)
    }
}
```

How to make the preview work?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I removed the use of the view model. The list only contains `CGColor` now. But the preview still doesn't work.

Comment: I would re-structure the code to have only 1 `ColorViewModel` with an array of `cgColors` 
inside of it. 
Create an single-source-of-truth like this: `@StateObject var colorViewModel = ColorViewModel()` 
pass it around your views as `@ObservedObject var colorViewModel: ColorViewModel`.
Use `colorViewModel.cgColors` array in your code. Similarly for the Preview.

Comment: As the above comment aludes to, `@State` shouldn't be used for an `ObservableObject` much less an array of them. Change to *one* `ObservableObject`, stored with `@StateObject` with a `@Published` array of values.

Comment: Hi guys thank you for your suggestion. I know there might be some design issues in my code but they seem not cause the preview problem directly. I have tried in a new xcode project. If I use the same way to render the subviews, even if the item of the list doesn't contain any special properties, the preview won't work either. I also found that if I make the list a normal property instead of a `@State`  the preview works just fine.

Comment: I rewrote the code so that the list only stores CGColor now. But the preview still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time searching for the solution, I guess this question should be "How to initialize `@State` property?"

Just change the initializer into:

```swift
init(_ colors: [CGColor]) {
        _capturedColors = State(initialValue: colors)
}
```

instead of setting the property directly.

The **underscore** in the `_capturedColors` is required.

The preview will work as expected.

`State(initialValue: colors)` is calling the initializer `init(wrappedValue:)` of `State`.

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/init(wrappedvalue:)), Apple tells you don't do this, just initialize it with the initial value in the declaration (most of the time it's enough).

But for my case, I need different initial value in the preview, so I guess I must do something like this.